# How to combine values of multiple rows in panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe file that split text into multiple rows, like:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | bbbb |
| ccccc | NaN |
| NaN | NaN |
| dddd | ffff |
| eeee | NaN |
| gg | NaN |

I hope to merge the value of each row to its next rows unless it is blank and get a data frame like:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| aaacccc | bbbb |
| ddddeeeegg | ffff |

Is there an efficient way to convert the dataframe in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mask and group from the rows with all NaNs, then [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the strings:

```
# rows with all NaN?
mask = df.isna().all(axis=1)
# create group starting with all-NaN rows
group = mask.cumsum()

# filter, group, aggregate
out = df[~mask].groupby(group).agg(lambda x: ''.join(x.dropna()))
```

output:

```
            A     B
0    aaaccccc  bbbb
1  ddddeeeegg  ffff
```

Comment: Thank you! That is really a nice way to deal with this problem. Could I know what all(1) is used for?

Comment: This is a shortcut for `all(axis=1)` which returns `True` if all values of the row are `True`